# Como verificar se todos os dados de minha lista existem no banco?

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

Preciso pegar os arquivos que estão em uma lista e comparar com os arquivos que estão em uma tabela no banco de dados, e saber se a quantidade de arquivos que tem na minha lista é a mesma quantidade da tabela.

```
 using Dapper;

 public bool ValidarPessoas(List <int> pessoas) {
  Dictionary < string, object > parametros = new Dictionary < string, object > ();
  parametros.Add("@pessoas", pessoas);
  parametros.Add("@quantidadePessoas", pessoas.Count);

  var query = @ " SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS 
   (
    SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM dbo.[Pessoa] WHERE ID in (@pessoas) HAVING COUNT(Pessoa.ID) = @quantidadePessoas
   )
  THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
  ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
  END ";

  string strConexao = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexao"].ConnectionString;
  using(var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strConexao))

  {
   return sqlConnection.QueryFirstOrDefault < bool > (query, parametros);
  }
 }
```

Quando executo esse código, recebo o erro:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ','.'

Comment: Pode incluir na pergunta como fica o valor da variável `query ` antes de executar?

Comment: Postei uma resposta, a ideia é boa, mas não sei se o código tem erro de digitação, se tiver corrige por favor :)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, Marconi. Pegamos o seu código como base para aperfeiçoarmos o nosso. Funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: Bacana Emmanuel, bom demais que pude ajudar. Se tiver algo errado no meu código por favor edite a minha resposta porque ela pode servir para futuros leitores do post!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No [dapper](/questions/tagged/dapper) não é preciso colocar `()` no IN(como é feito tradicionalmente numa query), isso é feita de maneira direta.

> O Dapper permite que você passe em IEnumerable e parametrize
>   automaticamente sua consulta.

Eu alterei seu código para ficar um pouco mais legível, perceba que minha consulta é simples e direta, ela retornar a quantidade de pessoas que tem na sua lista, com isto basta apenas comparar se o total retornado pelo banco é o mesmo que está na sua lista.

```
using Dapper;
using System.Linq;

public bool ValidarPessoas(List <int> pessoas) {
 var query = @ "SELECT COUNT(ID) 
                  FROM Pessoa 
                 WHERE ID 
                    IN @pessoas;"

 string strConexao = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexao"].ConnectionString;
 using(var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strConexao))

 {
  return sqlConnection.Query<int> (query, new {
    pessoas = pessoas
  }).Single() == pessoas.Count();
 }
}
```